# Nashorn - calling anonymous function from a different thread

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I'm trying to pass an anonymous function from JS back into Java, where I want it to be called later on by another thread.  The problem is that the bindings are missing when the code is executed in the context of another thread.  I've written a small example that demonstrates the problem.

```
//
// Get engine, create bindings object, execute script
//
ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();

SomeObject thing = new SomeObject();
bindings.put("thing", thing);

engine.eval(src, bindings);


//
// JS source:
//
thing.print("Hello from main thread");

thing.timer(function(){
    thing.print("Hello from the timer");
});



//
// SomeObject - intended to be called from JS to print to stdout,
// and to schedule some code to be run 100ms later
//
public class SomeObject {

    public void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public void timer(final Runnable f) {
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                f.run();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

The specific error is: `Exception in thread "Timer-0" <eval>:4 ReferenceError: "thing" is not defined`

I think I understand *why* this happens, my question is how to achieve this correctly.  Does Nashorn provide some way to bind the script context to the current thread?  Or, is attempting to call an anonymous function created in one thread from another a Bad Idea outright?